# Реализация REST API запроса на React

Tags: post, rest, reactjs

Подскажите, как реализовать REST API запрос по типу такого:
https://dadata.ru/api/suggest/. Хотел бы реализовать запрос на React. Делал  запросы на axios. Сложно понять какие параметры и как передать используя REST API  в этом примере.

Comment: react - это view. запросами занимается контроллер.

Comment: С React возможно сделать запросы к api. Axios

Comment: запросы делает Axios. react тут не причем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так

```
axios.post(
    'https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/fio', // url
    { 'query': FIO }, // data
    {
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Accept':        'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Token ' + API_KEY
        },
        // `withCredentials` indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests
        // should be made using credentials
        withCredentials: true // Может быть надо, а может быть нет
    } // config
)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // Здесь обработать ответ как надо
})
.catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

Из `React` должны получить `FIO` (текст запроса)
`API_KEY` - выданный при регистрации ключ

Comment: Верное и рабочее решение. Корректно работает без  withCredentials

Comment: Единственное, не могу получить response и использовать его значение в качестве  нового состояния в react.

Comment: `response.data.suggestions[0]...`

Comment: Значение в консоль выводится..Но за пределами промиса данное значение не могу использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Используя jQuery можно сделать так:

```
function () {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/fio",
        data: {"query": "Викт"},
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Token 1234" // тут должен быть ваш токен
        },
        success: function (data) {
            _this.setState(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Это функцию нужно добавить в соответсвующий обработчики к вашей компоненте. И не забудьте настроить CORS, так как вы обращаетесь к другому домену. Думаю, что под axios переделать не сложно.